# Table Formating in Numbers 3.0

Tags: numbers

In Numbers 3.0 is there a means to have a dark or heavier line every (5) lines for both the columns across and rows down?

Comment: Do you mean by calculation or manually?

Comment: I got it figured out.  It has to be done manually.

Comment: Excellent! You can answer your own question too so that others with the same issue can benefit. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

This can be accomplished manually.

### Changing cell border line weight

- Select the desired row(s) [Multiple rows can be selected using the <kbd>⌘</kbd>
  +Click method.]
- Select **Cell** tab in the **Format inspector** pane
- Select the desired border [i.e.: Top, bottom, left, right, all]
- Change the line style and thickness (weight)

[image: Cell border format settings]

Repeat for each desired row.  The **Copy Style / Paste Style** buttons can speed up your work as well.

---

[image: Formatted result]